# What the values of a, b, c, d of the formula about a 2d plane in 3d space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am trying to find the formula to draw a 2d plane (1,0,0) (0,1,0) in 3d space on https://www.math3d.org/

the sample equation is

```
$x^2-y^2$
```

in the range of [-2, 2], `math3d` gives this plot

[image]

A plane in 3-space has the equation

```
ax + by + cz = d
```

assume a plane (subspace) is spanned by 2 vectors (1,0,0) (0,1,0), what is the values of a, b, c, d?

Comment: A plane is determined by 3 points. On all 3 points $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and  $(0,0,0)$, $z = 0$. This means....

Comment: $a=b=d =0$ and $z=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting z = 0 may meet your need

this [link](https://www.math3d.org/yQloqz3k) give this figure

[image]